# Cruise Terminal at Malta

Tags: cruising, malta

We are going on a P&O cruise which starts at Malta / Valletta. 
We fly to Malta from the UK and our flight will arrive mid morning so we could get to the cruise terminal by lunchtime.

The ship doesn't leave until mid evening so I was wondering how close the cruise terminal was to anywhere interesting (for example the main town), if anyone knows how we'd get there (transport options)? And what the procedure is on a cruise for checking in to the ship and then leaving to explore. Is this even an option on arrival day? We have an organized "tour" on the day we get back there but nothing for departure day.

Comment: Questions about the check-in procedure are probably better asked directly of P&O than of a bunch of random strangers on the internet.

Comment: Do you know your earliest check-in time? It takes time to clean and restock a ship, so they may not let you check in early enough to have time to explore afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert you are no doubt correct, although I was really just looking for some information about what was close

Comment: Few general tips: Plan to arrive the day before embarkation in case there are delays.  Once you board on embarkation day, they really, really don't want you getting off.  Spend that afternoon exploring the ship.

Comment: A cruise from Malta with P&O will typically be a Fly Cruise, with the flight arranged by P&O, they also arrange the flights for you and will have shuttle buses at the terminal to arrange transfers to the ship. There are normally assurances in place that the ship will not leave port until all,passengers have boarded if a flight they have arranged is delayed.( The same applies for excursions that they have arranged at destinations, where as if you go Independant and miss the ship then you are in trouble.)

Answer (score 3):

The [Valletta cruise ship terminal](https://shorebee.com/en/malta/valletta/port) is at the Waterfront, which puts it right next to the fortress, one of the main tourist centres of Valletta. Many attractions are going to be walking distance from the ship terminal.

Comment: Lucky it docks at the waterfront. Could've been a bit tricky if it has to dock at the town square :)

Comment: The Waterfront is actually the name of a specific part of Valletta's huge harbour.

Comment: Yeah, I realised that when I followed the link

Answer (score 1):

From the cruise terminal it is easy to walk along the harbour front to the St Elmo Fort which has a number of attractions. If you want to visit the city centre there is no need to walk up the hill as if you walk along the harbour front towards the city centre you will get to the lift which takes you up to the Upper Barrakka Gardens (for a small fee). You are then within a hundred metres or so of the city centre. The Waterfront itself has mostly restaurants of various types and a few very tourist oriented shops.